# what is the MS SQL "platform" name in spring boot?

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot

for h2 db we define data-${platform}.sql in the properties as spring.datasource.platform=h2.

what is that name for MS SQL instead of h2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is "sql_server". Refer below link.

```
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/Database.html#SQL_SERVER
```